# JavaScript clock not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

I am using Raphael to make a simple clock for my website.  I am trying to plot the seconds hand to make it tick like a normal clock.

Here is the code I am running:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);

  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  backGround.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });

  var face = paper.circle(100, 100, 95);
  face.attr({
    "fill": "#f5f5f5",
    "stroke": "#ff0000",
    "stroke-width": "3"
  })

  var hand = paper.path("M100 110L100 25");
  hand.attr({
    stroke: "#ffff00",
    "stroke-width": 1
  });

  function startTime() {
    var hands = now.getSeconds();
    hands = checkTime(hands);
    hand.animate({
      transform: ['r', ((hands * 6) - 180), 200, 200]
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      startTime()
    }, 1000);

    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i
      };
      return i;

    }
    startTime();

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "it is not working" is not a sufficient problem description.

Comment: I can't see "now" ( var hands = now.getSeconds();) being defined anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to start the time function outside the function itself
- You missed a new Date statement
- I also moved the hands to 100x100
- Removed the useless second formatter.
- Changed the hand to black to see it better

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);

  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  backGround.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });

  var face = paper.circle(100, 100, 95);
  face.attr({
    "fill": "#f5f5f5",
    "stroke": "#ff0000",
    "stroke-width": "3"
  })

  var hand = paper.path("M100 110L100 25");
  hand.attr({
    stroke: "#000000",
    "stroke-width": 1
  });

  function startTime() {
    var now = new Date(),
        hands = now.getSeconds();
    hand.animate({
      transform: ['r', ((hands * 6) - 180), 100, 100]
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      startTime()
    }, 1000);
  }
  startTime();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.4/raphael-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is great, thank you so much for the help, made a lot of silly mistakes xx